# Can you pass the entries of a strut array to a int array? if so how?

Tags: arduino-mega, programming, array, struct

```
typedef struct {
  uint8_t  pitch;
}LearnNote;

#define  MAX_NOTE  500

LearnNote  Noteseq[MAX_NOTE]; 

int learnindex=0;
void loop() {
 MIDI.read();
}

void MyHandleNoteOn(byte channel, byte pitch, byte velocity){
Noteseq[learnindex].pitch=pitch;
learnindex++;
}
```

Comment: You are misusing the title. You are not supposed to squeeze your question there. Instead you should give a brief description of your Problem. Beside that in your particular case you can only cast your array from LearnNote to uint8_t. You need to loop over all entries and copy them one-by-one into an int-array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not very clear what you are asking, but I think you are saying can you do this

```
uint8_t anArray[MAX_NOTE];
anArray = Noteseq.pitch;
```

In general the answer is no.  However in this **specific** case off the top of my head I think you probably can (maybe).  You have a struct which only contains bytes.  The compiler will probably pack the sequentially so you will effectively have a contiguous sequence of bytes which you would be able to copy to the byte array by doing:

```
memcpy (anArray, Noteseq, MAX_NOTE);  // THIS IS BAD PRACTICE!
```

You can only do this in this case because the types are both 8bit numbers.  Its not a good idea to do this copy between an array of structs and a POD type array is just asking for trouble.

Instead use a function to do it.

```
int* CopyPitch (LearnNote* source, int* destination, int count)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
    {
        destination[i] = source[i].pitch;
    }
}
```

(You should really check for null pointers and stuff, but its just an example)